# How to inference Apache Spark Model via Java Spring based Backend microservice

Tags: apache-spark, mlops

We have data engineering and Machine learning pipeline where Similarity model
is created through Sparkml. Now for scalable inferencing, we are thinking
to host back-end service through Spring+java. Thus I have 2 questions:

1. How can we inference Sparkml model via Java+spring backend
2. Is there any other better approach which is also scalable?